# Simplify negation of inequality

Tags: coq, proof, inequality

I have a sub goal that is of the following form:

```
~ (My_term1) < (My_term2)
```

where `My_term1` and `My_term2` are both real numbers.

Is there a way to rewrite it as `(My_term1) >= (My_term2)` ?

I tried to use several tactics (`simpl` in particular) but I can not find the right way to achieve it.

Does anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the type of your terms. Knowing that they are reals is not enough to answer, because there are several different implementations of the reals.

Regardless, note that the fact you are looking for probably already has been proved as a lemma (or possibly the `My_term2 <= My_term1` version). You can search for it like so:

```
Search (~ (_ < _)) (_ <= _).
```

or

```
Search (~ (_ < _)) (_ >= _).
```

You can play around with the search terms to make it more or less specific depending on whether you are getting too many or too few search results. For example, here is a more specific version:

```
Search (~ (?a < ?b)) (?b <= ?a).
```

and a less specific version:

```
Search (_ < _).
```

Searching Coq libraries unfortunately requires some practice, because the searching is quite literal. Many times we have a specific formulation of a result in mind that is nowhere to be found, but there is an equivalent but different formulation somewhere. That's why being less specific in the search can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ssreflect/mathcomp for your reals, the order.v file offers the `leNgt` rewrite rule, based on boolean negation:

```
Lemma leNgt x y : (x ≤ y) = ~~ (y < x).
```

Comment: If anyone else is confused by this, `~~` seems to be a mathcomp notation for boolean negation (and not, say, double application of proposition negation `~`). [Here is the source](https://math-comp.github.io/htmldoc/mathcomp.algebra.ssrnum.html#Num.Theory.real_leNgt).